# diff between two files skipping some specific lines (ex. logs)

Tags: logging, diff, patch

How to create patch file (containing differences between two files) using **diff which not include lines containing some specific pattern (ex. lines containing logs)**?

I need such tool because I sometimes need to create patches based on two version of files after some development. During development I am putting many debug log lines into test file or just changing debug level (ex. from DEBUG to ERROR level).

After that I need to remove those debug changes manually before creating patch file based on diff tool. Is it possible to use some diff tool options or create some script which will allow me automatically avoid all changes related to to debug message.

Example:

File1:

```
Log(INFO, "test1");
Log(INFO, "test2");
int a = 10;
Log(INFO, "test3");
```

File2:

```
Log(ERROR, "test1");
Log(INFO, "test2");
int a = 20;
int b = 30;
Log(INFO, "test3");
Log(ERROR, "test4");
```

After following command:

```
diff -u File1 File2
```

I receive output:

```
-Log(INFO, "test1");
+Log(ERROR, "test1");
 Log(INFO, "test2");
-int a = 10;
+int a = 20;
+int b = 30;
 Log(INFO, "test3");
+Log(ERROR, "test4");
```

I would like to see following output after applying script or diff tool options which I need:

```
 Log(INFO, "test2");
-int a = 10;
+int a = 20;
+int b = 30;
 Log(INFO, "test3");
```

So any changes related to log message should be omitted. All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to filter out the log messages would be to first translate all log messages into one common thing (like `Log(INFO, "")`) and then collapse all repeated log messages into one. Running

```
$ diff -u  <(sed 's/Log(.*)/Log(INFO, "")/' file1 | uniq) <(sed 's/Log(.*)/Log(INFO, "")/' file2 | uniq)
--- /dev/fd/63  2014-03-19 23:38:33.976616099 +0100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2014-03-19 23:38:33.976616099 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 Log(INFO, "");
-int a = 10;
+int a = 20;
+int b = 30;
 Log(INFO, "");
$
```

gives what you want bases on the simple examples although the `sed 's/Log(.*)/Log(INFO, "")/' file... | uniq` command is by no means very sophisticated and might be too aggressive. You probably want to put it into a script if used more than a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to remove the `Log` lines using [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/). This is a tool designed to modify source code in various ways. Just removing something is trivially simple. Create a file rm_log.cocci with the following content:

```
@@
@@
-       Log(...);
```

Use it as

```
$ spatch --sp-file rm_log.cocci file1 -o file1b
init_defs_builtins: /usr/share/coccinelle/standard.h
HANDLING: file1
diff = 
--- file1       2014-03-21 12:01:24.000000000 +0100
+++ /tmp/cocci-output-29762-97a65a-file1      2014-03-21 12:07:05.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,7 +1,5 @@
 void f(void)
 {
-       Log(INFO, "test1");
-       Log(INFO, "test2");
+
        int a = 10;
-       Log(INFO, "test3");
 }
```

(and correspondingly for file2), and then you will get the diff without Log niose:

```
$ diff -u file1b file2b 
--- file1b      2014-03-21 12:07:05.000000000 +0100
+++ file2b      2014-03-21 12:07:15.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 void f(void)
 {

-       int a = 10;
+       int a = 20;
+       int b = 30;
 }
```